# Link the text in the text box to a pre-defined list

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter, autocomplete

I am working on a project with PHP, Jquery, CodeIgniter. We have a database of products which is stored in a MySQL table.

We have a PHP page where the user can register a service request. The requirement is that if the user starts typing `@product1` in the textbox, we should be able to link it to `product1` in our database.

It is quite similar to the way facebook does it, but the requirement is that as soon as the user starts typing `@`, our page should be intelligent to guess the product and give the options. Like for e.g. if the user is typing `@pro...` the system should give him `product1`, `product2` etc.

Please help. I can elaborate if I am not clear.

Comment: Its Autocomplete feature using `AJAX`

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [jquery.mentionsInput](http://podio.github.io/jquery-mentions-input/) plugin.

```
$('textarea.mention').mentionsInput({
  onDataRequest:function (mode, query, callback) {
    // here instead of having all data you can do an AJAX-request to your server
    var data = [
      { id:1, name:'product1', avatar:'..', type: 'product' },
      { id:2, name:'product2', avatar:'..', type: 'product' },
    ];
    data = _.filter(data, function(item) { return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1 });

    callback.call(this, data);
  }
});
```

And then parse `@[product1](product:1)` on the php side

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11083318)

Comment: I was thinking to comment my answer but this demands minimum 50 reputation and i dont have that much so i posted this as an answer :)
I just want to help the guy...

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your answer except for that it did not contain some excerpts from that link and explanation on how it may be suitable. Added some code